# Is it possible to create an IPV6 Only Application Load Balancer (ALB) in AWS (as of Dec 2023)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

It is possible to create an IPV4 only or a dual stack (4 and 6) ALB in AWS. Is it possible to create an ALB that supports only IPV6 on the public interface?

AWS will start charging for IPV4 public IPs starting Feb 2024. There are 2 IPs assigned per ALB so about $86/yr extra costs. Regardless of the cost, is there a way to

1. Shut off IPV4 support on the public interfaces leaving only IPV6
2. Support ONLY IPv6 traffic from the public internet, but let the ALB translate to IPV4 if the target EC2 instance is IPV4 only.

Docs seem to suggest that #2 seem to be supported today should the client come in via IPV6 but there seems to be no option in the AWS Console for #1. If there is via AWS CLI it is not documented.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ipv6-support.html refers only to Elastic Load Balancing (without specifically mentioning ALB)  and says IPV6 only support is not available.

Hoping that concurrent with AWS deciding to charge for public IPs even for ALBs, they would provide a way for IPv6 only support for environments where ipV4 is not needed.

Comment: The page you linked says: Elastic Load Balancing IPv6 Only: Load balancers: No Target groups: Yes. So I take that to mean Load balancers do not support IPv6 Only at this time.